# Error with generating reset password email via Firebase SDK Node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Currently I am trying to implement a reset Link for an individual who forgets their password.  I keep getting an error that states sendCustomPasswordResetEmail is not defined.  I am fairly new to Firebase SDK so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my function:

```
exports.resetPassword = (req, res) => {
  const userEmail = req.body.email
  admin
    .auth()
    .generatePasswordResetLink(userEmail)
    .then(link => {
      // Construct password reset email template, embed the link and send
      // using custom SMTP server.
      return sendCustomPasswordResetEmail(userEmail, link)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: You have to provide the implementation of sendCustomPasswordResetEmail to send the email. That's not an API provided by the SDK.

Comment: is there anything about this in the docs or how would i go about this?

Comment: You choose your implementation for sending this custom email.  That's out of scope for Firebase documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to send a custom email? Otherwise you could act as client and send a normal password reset email as described in the [docs for web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email).